# docker-compose logs successful message

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to have docker-compose log a message when all containers have started after `docker-compose up` ?

*I know that it should not be docker to assess whether a container started successfully or not, but I am wondering if there should be some kind of message when the exposed ports are reachable?*

Comment: Good question! I usually run something like `curl` or [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to wait for the services to be there. Compose does not know when the initialization has completed, and I don't see how it could know that based on the multitude of possible services that you are able to start.

Comment: ...the thing is that testing ports might not be the right way to go either: some containers might not even expose ports and have their "output" on a volume or else. maybe there should be some kind of protocol in container logging? something saying "hello, my startup phase ended"

Comment: Yes, of course, there's a million different use cases and no standard way at the moment...

Comment: The console shows when `docker-comose up` is run, right? Something different you looking for?